# Add a .last class to the last <li> in each ul.sub-menu

Tags: menus, sub-menu

I've seen a lot of code on how to add a `first` and `last` class to a WordPress menu, but in my instance I would like to add a `last` class to the last li in the sub-menu that WP generates. Here's what I would like to achieve in it's simplest form.

```
<ul>
    <li>Menu item one</li>
    <li class="has-sub-menu">Menu item two
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>Sub menu item one</li>
            <li>Sub menu item two</li>
            <li class="last">Sub menu item three</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Menu item three</li>
</ul>
```

And here is what I currently have, that adds first and last classes to only the parent menu items. Could this be adapted?

```
function add_first_and_last($items) {
    $items[1]->classes[] = 'first';
    $items[count($items)]->classes[] = 'last';
    return $items;
}

add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'add_first_and_last');
```

I would like to stick with php for this and not use either `:last-child` (want it to work in ie7 & 8) or jQuery.

Comment: Could you link to the code that you've seen how to add a first and last class to a WordPress menu? It seems that this could just be adapted slightly for your purpose. Failing that a custom walker should be able to do the trick.

Comment: Hi Stephen, code is posted in my question. Not too clued up with custom walkers, any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the following in your `functions.php`

```
class SH_Last_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu{

   function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ) {

        $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];

       //If the current element has children, add class 'sub-menu'
       if( isset($children_elements[$element->$id_field]) ) { 
            $classes = empty( $element->classes ) ? array() : (array) $element->classes;
            $classes[] = 'has-sub-menu';
            $element->classes =$classes;
       }
        // We don't want to do anything at the 'top level'.
        if( 0 == $depth )
            return parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );

        //Get the siblings of the current element
        $parent_id_field = $this->db_fields['parent'];      
        $parent_id = $element->$parent_id_field;
        $siblings = $children_elements[ $parent_id ] ;

        //No Siblings?? 
        if( ! is_array($siblings) )
            return parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );

        //Get the 'last' of the siblings.
        $last_child = array_pop($siblings);
        $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];

            //If current element is the last of the siblings, add class 'last'
        if( $element->$id_field == $last_child->$id_field ){
            $classes = empty( $element->classes ) ? array() : (array) $element->classes;
            $classes[] = 'last';
            $element->classes =$classes;
        }

        return parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
    }
}
```

### Usage

Where you use `wp_nav_menu` and you wish to have the 'last' class added, specify the walker above:

```
wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location'=>'primary','walker' => new SH_Last_Walker(),'depth' => 0) );
```

`theme_location` and `depth` can be whatever you like, the important part is the `walker` attribute.

### Side remarks

This code can be improved - potentially by un-setting each element in the `$children_elements[$parent_id]` array when its called and checking when it's down to the last element (i.e. when it contains only one element). I think `wp_list_filter` would be suitable here. This might not improve efficiency, but might be neater.

Also, you can hard-code the parent and id fields - I've not done this for portability. The following class could be able to extend any of the provided extensions of the Walker Class (page lists, category lists etc).

Comment: Thank you Stephen, appreciate it. Worked great, although I don't understand enough about walkers to understand what is going on in the above code. Will do some further reading on walkers. On another note, I added some code into your walker that I had somewhere else to add a `has-sub-menu` class to the parent menu item. It works fine, but am wondering if there is anything wrong with the implentation. I added the below code just inside the walker function.

Comment: $id = $this->db_fields['id'];
     if(isset($children_elements[$element->$id])) {
      $element->classes[] = 'has-sub-menu';  
      return parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
     }

Comment: I don't think you want/need to `return parent::display_element`. I'll edit the answer to reflect what I think you are after.

Comment: Hi thanks for your update. It seems to be adding the class in a weird place (within the submenu), and not on the top level menu item. I've updated my original question to reflect where I would like the class name. I did catch the misspelling of your class name (slightly different to mine) but this didn't work either.

Comment: I've edited the answer again. All I've done is move the extra checks to the top, so the class should always be added to the `<li>` tag of an element which has children. I've tested it on TwentyEleven and it works as expected. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen! Sorry it won't let me upvote twice :)

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery would look something like this;

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    $('.sub-menu > li:last-child').addClass('last-item');

} );
```

But as for the PHP, please take a look at this answer provided by Rarst [HERE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1744/adding-first-last-css-classes-to-menus) and see if this helps you at all.

## UPDATE

Rart' solution from the above link does it fact work and the code snippet is;

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'first_last_class' );

function first_last_class( $items ) {

    $first = strpos( $items, 'class=' );

    if( false !== $first )
         $items = substr_replace( $items, 'first ', $first+7, 0 );

    $last = strripos( $items, 'class=');

    if( false !== $last )
         $items = substr_replace( $items, 'last ', $last+7, 0 );

    return $items;
}
```

The output gave me something like this;

```
<ul>
    <li class="first">Menu item one</li>
    <li>Menu item two
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="first">Sub menu item one</li>
            <li>Sub menu item two</li>
            <li class="last">Sub menu item three</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="last">Menu item three</li>
</ul>
```

Which then means you can style your `ul ul li` element via CSS selectors successfully.

Comment: thanks but as per question I want to avoid using jQuery. I've seen that answer from Rarst but unfortunately it only adds the classes to the parent menu items and not the sub-menu items

Comment: Sorry Andrew I read that incorrectly. I'll attempt to run a test and see if I can solve this.

Comment: @Andrew I just tested Rarst' solution and it worked for me.

Comment: it worked on the 2nd level .sub-menu? Doesn't seem to work for me, but does work correctly on the first level. I'll have another look...

Comment: No luck here, only affects the top level and not the `.sub-menu`. Tried on a new install of Twenty Eleven.

Comment: Well that's perculiar because its working for me. Have you tried it on your target theme?

Comment: @andrew Ok I ran a test on the Twenty Eleven theme and it produces the same result you are getting. However running it on a custom theme I get the correct result. So there obviously is something going on in the functions.php file or any sub-functions file being called upon which is interfering with this process. Do you intend to use the Twenty Eleven theme or are you looking to add this functionality to another theme of your choice? Custom, free or premium purchased?

Comment: @userabuser - generally this won't produce the desired effect. `wp_nav_menu_items` filters the final HTML I believe - and so you only find the first and last elements in that HTML.

Comment: @StephenHarris The snippet above (taken from Rart's answer) works for me in my custom built theme framework. But it does not work for the OP or myself in Twently Eleven. So there must be something else the TE theme is doing with the `wp_nav_menu` which is causing problem described by the OP. Whilst this snippet does work, I'd still like to know why it does not in TE theme. Do you have any more information concerning this? A custom walker, as you've provided, is the other alternative. But quite a number of more lines to boot! However if that's the solution that works for the OP then great.

Comment: I'd be happy to discuss this in [chat] :)

Comment: @userabuser Appreciate you testing this for me. I was actually trying to get it working while using it my own theme I was developing before trying it in twenty eleven. I'll definitely keep it in my code arsenal and see if I can get it working for future use when I don't need the walker class.

Answer (score 2):

something to consider: while IE7 and IE8 don't support last-child, they DO support first-child.  so depending on what CSS you need to apply differently to the last item, you could reverse it.

also, FWIW, your theme is already using jQuery in other areas by default (comment section, for example) so that would be a quicker and cleaner option.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I know about :first-child support in IE7+ but :last-child was important in this instance. I'm not a big fan of relying on jQuery for adding classes like this.

Comment: Just to note, this is exactly what jQuery is meant for.

Comment: I guess I'm thinking that if I can do it without relying on jQuery then I might as well. If JS was not turned on it would affect the overall design. Thanks though, I see your point.

Comment: I can't find the exact numbers, but something like less than 2% of users have JS turned off. If they do, then they are most likely accustomed to not seeing much of *anything* on the web.

Comment: The Mozilla survey is from 2010 , the average amount of users with js disabled (worldwide) was 1%. Doing this type of stuff in php is just silly.